# Rails devise controller before filter to only show users their data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Basically I want it so that on my views when you sign in you are only able to view the projects and assets associated with that project if you are the one who created them. Here is my current controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController


  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end


  def new
      @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
      @project = Project.new(project_params)
      @project.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Name successfully added."
      redirect_to(@project, :action => 'show')
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end

  end

  private

    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:name, :id, :user_id)
    end

end
```

Also as my user has_many projects and projects has_many assets and projects has a user_id column and index, does that mean that a created asset is automatically associated with that user or do I need to add a user_id to assets as well.

The reason I say this is because I want to be able to in my view:

```
#views/projects/show.html.erb

<% current_user.assets.each do |f| %>
<%= f.name %>
<%= f.url %>
<% end %>
```

or something like that.

Also if on that same page I wanted to add a create new asset button would I need to create an asset controller with a create action or could I just have it in the projects controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is scope `Project` through `current_user`, like so:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)

    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Name successfully added."
      redirect_to(@project, :action => 'show')
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  private

  def project_params
    # removed :user_id for security reasons (see below)
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :id)
  end
end
```

> Also as my user has_many projects and projects has_many assets and
>   projects has a user_id column and index, does that mean that a created
>   asset is automatically associated with that user or do I need to add a
>   user_id to assets as well.

To do this, map the relation using `has_many through:` --

```
class User
  has_many :projects
  has_many :assets, through: :projects
end
```

> Also, if I wanted to create a new asset in the projects/show.html.erb
>   view, would I just create an assets controller with a new method and
>   then route the button to that method? or could I do this inside the
>   projects controller?

For this, you would use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `Profile` model:

```
class Profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end
```

Then update your permitted `project_params`:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :id, assets_attributes: [:etc])
end
```

Couple of notes. Update `assets_attributes: [:etc]` with `Asset` attributes that should be accessible. That might be `:name`, `:file`, etc. Second, notice I've removed `:user_id`. This is a **very** important concept. Permitting `:user_id` means the form can be injected with that attribute. In this case, it would allow users to assign the created `Project` to any user they like.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to create a new asset in the projects/show.html.erb view, would I just create an assets controller with a new method and then route the button to that method? or could I do this inside the projects controller?

Comment: @HarryLucas in that case, you would add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets` in your `Project` model, then update `project_params` permit the attributes. I'll update my answer.